# ElasticSearch Aggregation help required

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Currently, I have a field which is a map. I need to aggregate on the unique keys and the sum of its value.

For example

```
   {
        "_index": "inx-flow",
        "_type": "default",
        "_id": "acc4566-23456",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
            "@Timestamp": "2018-06-20T09:21:43.892Z",
            "taskType": "typeOne",
            "imageId": "adadiddidd123",
            "taskCreated": "2018-06-20T09:21:43.841Z",
            "scope": {
                "productA": 5
            },
            "taskPriority": 123,
            "taskName": "typeOneName",
            "metrics": {},
            "taskId": "acc4566-23456",
            "taskEvent": "Pending"
        }

}

{

        "_index": "inx-flow",
        "_type": "default",
        "_id": "acc4566-23456",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
            "@Timestamp": "2018-06-20T09:21:43.892Z",
            "taskType": "typeOne",
            "imageId": "adadiddidd123",
            "taskCreated": "2018-06-20T09:21:43.841Z",
            "scope": {
                "productA": 1
            },
            "taskPriority": 123,
            "taskName": "typeOneName",
            "metrics": {},
            "taskId": "acc4566-23456",
            "taskEvent": "Pending"
        }
}

{
        "_index": "inx-flow",
        "_type": "default",
        "_id": "acc4566-23456",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
            "@Timestamp": "2018-06-20T09:21:43.892Z",
            "taskType": "typeOne",
            "imageId": "adadiddidd123",
            "taskCreated": "2018-06-20T09:21:43.841Z",
            "scope": {
                "productB": 1
            },
            "taskPriority": 123,
            "taskName": "typeOneName",
            "metrics": {},
            "taskId": "acc4566-23456",
            "taskEvent": "Pending"
        }

}
```

For the above, if I want to aggregate of scope across entries I want aggregation like ProductA 6 ProductB 1 How to achieve it. I am able to achieve if I hardcore the field names but I don't want hardcoded values. My code

```
try ( RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient()){

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate todayDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate yesterday = todayDate.minusDays(5);
        String toDate = dtf.format(todayDate);
        String fromDate = dtf.format(yesterday);
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.size(10000);
        searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().
                filter(QueryBuilders.commonTermsQuery("taskEvent", "Pending")).
                filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@Timestamp").from(fromDate).to(toDate)));

        TermsAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms("scope")
                .field("scope.productA");
        aggregation.subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum")
              .field("scope.productA"));

        searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(aggregation);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse  = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);

        SearchHit[] hits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

        for(SearchHit hit : hits){
            Map responseMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
            responseMap.forEach((key,value)->
                System.out.println("Key "+key+ " Value "+value));

        }

        System.out.println("**********"+searchResponse.getHits().getHits().length);
        System.out.println("********* " + searchResponse.getAggregations());

        Terms agg = searchResponse.getAggregations().get("scope");
        for(Terms.Bucket bucket : agg.getBuckets()){
            Sum sum = bucket.getAggregations().get("sum");
            System.out.println("Sum " + sum.getValue());
        }
}
```

Could you help me understand how to aggregate without hard-coding the key name? Like I want to give the map root and aggregation should be based on the key and its values

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only feasible way is to [fetch the mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/indices-get-mapping.html) first and generate a list of aggregations based on the `properties` set of the given key in the mapping.

You could also achieve this with [scripted metric aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) but it is experimental, cumbersome and might be not efficient at all.

Hope that helps.